# Датафрейм из многомерного списка

Tags: python, dataframe

Как из многомерного списка `p` получить датафрейм df с готовыми названиями столбцов как ниже написано?

```
p = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['one','two','tree'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas 
data=[['a1','a2'],['b1','b2'],['c1','c2']]
df=pandas.DataFrame(data)
'''
    0   1
0  a1  a2
1  b1  b2
2  c1  c2
'''
df.T
'''
    0   1   2
0  a1  b1  c1
1  a2  b2  c2
'''
```

Comment: Сорри, а названия столбцов совпадают с теми, которые задал ТС?

Answer (score 2):

Это же пример, из любого источника по Pandas:

```
p = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(p,columns = ['one','two','tree'])
print (df)
```

Результат:

```
   one  two  tree
0    1    2     3
1    1    2     3
2    1    2     3
```